# How to use the magento module migration toolkit

Tags: module, magento-1.9, migrate, toolkit, magento-2.0

Lately I have downloaded and composser installed a magento code migration toolkit from GIT, which can migrates modules in format of Magento 1.x to format of Magento 2.0, It helps in reduce the time consuming for us to typing the php, modules, and other time consuming codes of the Magento 2.0 Module.

However, I have stucked at here, I don't know what this mean...:

Step one: Migrate Magento 1.x module structure to Magento 2.0 structure (bin/migrate.php migrateModuleStructure).

Step two: Migrate Magento 1.x layout.xml Magento 2.0 structure file structure. (bin/migrate.php convertLayout).

Step three: Migrate PHP code (bin/migrate.php convertPhpCode).

Actually what is meant by “migrate” from these steps?
 [If you feel intersted, you also can download from here.](https://github.com/magento/code-migration)

Comment: Hi, may i know how is your progress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- **For Step One in your question**,

  `Step one: Migrate Magento 1.x module structure to Magento 2.0 structure (bin/migrate.php migrateModuleStructure).`

it is use to remove the code pools (core, community, local), and also aggregate module files in single directory.

- **For Step Two**

  `Step two: Migrate Magento 1.x layout.xml Magento 2.0 structure file structure. (bin/migrate.php convertLayout).`

it is to breakdown layout files by handles. It also formats out XML files such as block types and block names.

- **For Step Three in your question**,

  `Step three: Migrate PHP code (bin/migrate.php convertPhpCode).`

it is for breaking down the controllers by actions. It also formats the php files.

---

You may refer to the youtube video below for more understanding:

-[Imagine 2016 - Developer Deep Dive: Magento 1.x to Magento 2 Code Migration Tool](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lXJ6rMdQvkk)

Comment: @Soon Fei Grey Don Please accept my answer if it is correct :)

Comment: Yup it solved my question! Thank you for your recommendation. 

Sorry for late reply since I just found my access to this account